# Purpose of using alloc in objective C

Tags: objective-c

What is the difference between

```
 NSNumber *number = [[NSNumber alloc]initWithInt:13];
```

and

```
NSNumber *number = [NSNumber initWithInt:13];
```

Why alloc when both solves the same purpose?

Comment: For your latter example, I assume you meant `[NSNumber numberWithInt:13]`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`[NSNumber initWithInt:]` won't work, because `-initWithInt:` is an *instance method* and you're sending it to the *class*. `[NSNumber numberWithInt:]` will work, but that's (probably) a convenience wrapper around `[[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:]`.

Foundation (and everything built on it, including UIKit and probably your own classes in an iOS app too) uses the [two-stage creation](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1398610) technique. The `+alloc` method is just responsible for *allocating enough memory* for your instance and setting a pointer that says what class it's an instance of. Custom set-up can then be done in an `-init` (or `-init…`) method.

The advantage of this system is that your custom initialisers do not have to concern themselves with allocating memory for the object. The disadvantage is that client code has to call both stages, which is why convenience constructors like `+new` and `+numberWithInt:` are created.

At a more advanced level, the two-stage creation process is also used to support *class clusters* like `NSArray` and `NSNumber`, where the exact type to use is not known until the initialiser is called. `+alloc` can return a placeholder object that then replaces itself during the second stage.

Comment: Historically, the separation was used to allow memory allocated via a different allocator to then be initialized as an object. This was abandoned long ago because it was too damned fragile at deallocation.  The two stage allocator also allows classes to return a different, often cached already existing, instance upon initialization (which is common behavior in class clusters, but orthogonal to clusters).

Comment: In the context of NSNumber, `+alloc` returns an instance of ` NSPlaceholderNumber` (i guess this is a singleton because it reports a retain count of (ul)4294967295/(l)-1). When you call `initWithInt:` on this object it calls CoreFoundation's `CFNumberCreate()`. CoreFoundation also has some caching for a small range of numbers (look for "__CFNumberCache" in http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/CF/CF-744.12/CFNumber.c )

Comment: @MartinUllrich CFNumber and NSNumber also use tagged pointers for integer values in range.

Answer (score 2):

Graham Lee already gave the correct answer that's why you should accept it as the correct one. Nowadays, in my opinion `[NSNumber numberWithInt:42];` is just a short cut of `[[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:42]`

Comment: And NSNumber *var = @(expression);  is even shorter ;)

Comment: Same as NSNumber *number = @13;