# What's the big advantage of the two-stage creation approach used in Cocoa?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, constructor

I've been programming in Objective-C for a couple of years now and
I'm currently writing a little essay of some principles of the language for college.

While doing that, I stumbled upon the two-stage creation approach followed by Cocoa most of you ObjC programmers will be using every day (for those of you not familiar with the term, it's about using [[MyObject alloc] initWithParameters:...] instead of having regular constructors as known from other languages).

I read the chapter of the book Cocoa Design Patterns which can be found online [here](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1339553)  and also another version [here](http://volonbolon.net/post/634999801/two-stage-creation-in-cocoa).

However, I'm still not getting the point really.
Let's consider the example from the second link:

- The author investigates what would happen if NSString would be using classical constructors instead of the two-stage creation process
- he says that this would be bad as you would probably need to overwrite a lot of constructors if you create a subclass of it.

And this is not clear to me! If you would need some specific initialization of variables, you would also need to write the same amount of different initializer functions than constructors! And if you don't have to do that, you could as well not implement the constructor and let the call be forwarded to the superclass.

The other example from the first link of creating an image in different memory areas makes a lot more sense to me. However, I think it is too made up to be true. If you would simply pass a flag as another parameter to specify the intended memory region this problem would be solved without the combinatorial explosion of constructors. Also, I don't see how this would be solved when using two-stage creation. How would you tell your constructor that it should allocate on the GPU and not in the normal RAM in that case?

Would love to hear your thoughts about this!
Would really like to understand why this is the way it is and if it's really better than classic constructors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Buck & Yacktman explain it most clearly on page 30 (in my copy, anyway) in the section labelled *Motivation*, but sometimes it helps to understand something by considering an extreme case. Imagine  that for some reason you had **5** different ways to allocate memory for an object, and **10** ways that you could initialize the object. If allocation and initialization are performed together in the same method, you'd need **5 * 10 = 50** different constructors in order to provide all 10 initialization mechanisms for each of the 5 allocation mechanisms. By implementing allocation and initialization in separate methods, you only need **5 + 10 = 15** methods to perform the same set of capabilities.

So that savings alone is pretty compelling. It might seem unrealistic to have as many as 10 initializers in a single class, but consider that subclasses would *also* need to provide a version of each initializer for every allocation mechanism. In practice, it's very uncommon to write your own allocator, but `NSObject` itself provides two: `+alloc` and `+allocWithZone:`. Any object should be able to initialize itself using memory allocated with either of those methods, and that means that every subclass of `NSObject` (in other words, nearly every class) would have to provide two constructor versions for every way that an object can be initialized.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! That makes perfect sense! The approach from the second link I mentioned totally confused me ...

Answer (score 4):

@bbum in [a comment to a SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15619565/451475) states:

> Historically, the separation was used to allow memory allocated via a
>   different allocator to then be initialized as an object. This was
>   abandoned long ago because it was too damned fragile at deallocation.
>   The two stage allocator also allows classes to return a different,
>   often cached already existing, instance upon initialization (which is
>   common behavior in class clusters, but orthogonal to clusters).

Note that the keyword new can be used in place of alloc-init if there are no parameters:

```
NSString *s = [NSString new];
```

This is no longer considered "bad form", some newer Apple documentation uses this form. It is functionally identical to:

```
NSString *s = [[NSString alloc] init];
```

Comment: I did not know that! I thought "new" was somewhat deprecated and should not be used. Thanks for pointing out!

Comment: For a long period it was discouraged but that seems to have changed around the time ARC was provided. ARC changed many things such as `[NSArray array]` vs. `[NSArray alloc] init]`, under ARC there is no real benefit to many of the convenience constructors.

Answer (score 1):

I think that possibly a way to explain it is considering that `NSObject` has two different allocation methods: [`alloc`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/nsobject_class/reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSObject/alloc) and [`allocWithZone:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/nsobject_class/reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSObject/allocWithZone%3a).

`allocWithZone` means (meant, actually) that you can (could) specify where (in which zone) you would like to allocate your object; then, once you get the memory, you would initialise it.

So having two steps could serve this goal: first you allocate the memory for it (where you need it), then you initialise it. Without such scheme, you would need to pass your zone (ore more generally allocation requirements) in your constructors explicitly.

Think also of what happens in C++ (not that it is related in any way to C or Objective C, just as an example): C++ classes have constructors, but they also have [`operator new`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/new/operator%20new/), which can be overridden when you have specific requirements as to memory allocation.

In any case, as the Apple docs put it about `allocWithZone`:

> This method exists for historical reasons; memory zones are no longer used by Objective-C.

Comment: Two stage creation is still used in some Apple class clusters.